# ZFS on Linux: How do I correctly configure the vdev_id.conf file and trigger vdev aliasing?

Tags: linux, zfs, zfsonlinux, kernel-modules

I have been trying to get ZFS on Linux to read / process the vdev_id.conf file and give me a /dev/disk/by-vdev directory, to no avail.

I have a SAS HBA with redundant connectivity to several hard drives.

I have read the documentation but I am not quite sure what to put in the PCI_ID column.

I have left everything defaulted out, and still I do not even see the directory "by-vdev".

I run the command "udevadm trigger", but I get to errors or output, just a return.

This is my file:

```
      multipath yes

        #       PCI_SLOT HBA PORT  CHANNEL NAME
        channel 85:00.0  1         A
        channel 85:00.0  0         B
        channel 86:00.0  1         A
        channel 86:00.0  0         B
```

I have enabled multipathd, removed the blacklist-all directive with "mpathconf --enable" command, and got the mpath devices in /dev/mapper.

Not sure where to go from here to populate the by-vdev directory.

OS is CentOS 7.3 with Kernel 4.8

Thanks for any help given!

Comment: Huh? What are you talking about?

Comment: What is vdev_id.conf?  What file is "This is my file"? Does [this](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/pkg-zfs/wiki/HOWTO-install-EL7-(CentOS-RHEL)-to-a-Native-ZFS-Root-Filesystem) or [this](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/issues/5191)  help you in any way?

Comment: vdev_id.conf is a file that maps logical names to physical devices. In a complex configuration, you can map multiple paths to one logical name. The documentation and comments in the code are not clear enough for me to get how to structure it.

Answer (score 1):

After you setup your conf file you need to do a udevadm trigger for your new devices to show up it will make a diretory under /dev/disk called by-vdev that will have the alias names for all your disk in it.